# clangTidy linting corecrt_wstdio.h

Tags: c++, llvm-clang, clang-tidy, clangpowertools

i am attempting to use clangTidy on a legacy codebase. in trying the simplest test case on one file, i am getting this error that i have no idea how to prevent.  I believe this comes from my file including StdAfx, which includes some standard headers, which are somehow being linted?  I have removed some of the verbose lines... any ideas?

I am using Clang Power Tools to invoke this, but i think the result would be the same regardless.

```
Start Clang Tidy

VERBOSE: clang-build.ps1 invocation args: 
  aVcxprojToCompile = C:\Dev\Projects\myProject\Src\Foo\PROJECT.vcxproj 
  aCppToCompile = Checksum.cpp 
  aVcxprojConfigPlatform = Debug|x64 
  aClangCompileFlags = -Werror -std=c++14 -Wall -fms-compatibility-version=19.10 -fms-compatibility -Wmicrosoft 
-Wno-invalid-token-paste -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value 
  Verbose = True 
  aTidyFixFlags = -*,modernize-use-equals-default,modernize-use-equals-delete 
  aVisualStudioVersion = 2015 
  aVisualStudioSku = Professional 
  aDirectory = C:\Dev\Projects\myProject\Src 
  aDisableNameRegexMatching = True 

VERBOSE: Clang job tool: clang-tidy.exe
VERBOSE: Clang job args[0]: "C:\Dev\Projects\myProject\Src\Foo\Common\Checksum.cpp" 
-checks=-*,modernize-use-equals-default,modernize-use-equals-delete 
-header-filter="C:\\Dev\\Projects\\myProject\\Src" -quiet -fix-errors -- -Werror -std=c++14 -Wall 
-fms-compatibility-version=19.10 -fms-compatibility -Wmicrosoft -Wno-invalid-token-paste -Wno-unknown-pragmas 
-Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -D_FooDLL -DZLIB_DLL -D_DEBUG -D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=1 -D_DLL -D_USRDLL 
-DNOMINMAX -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -DVL_STATIC_LINKING -D_BIND_TO_CURRENT_VCLIBS_VERSION -D_MT -DSS_NO_CONVERSION 
-D_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES=1 -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE
1: C:\Dev\Projects\myProject\Src\Foo\Common\Checksum.cpp
49 warnings and 3 errors generated.
Error while processing 
C:\Dev\Projects\myProject\Src\Foo\Common\Checksum.cpp.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(1488): error: inline declaration of '__vswprintf_l' not allowed in block scope [clang-diagnostic-error]
    int, __RETURN_POLICY_SAME, _CRT_STDIO_INLINE, __CRTDECL, __swprintf_l, __vswprintf_l, _vswprintf_s_l,
                               ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(21): message: expanded from macro '_CRT_STDIO_INLINE'
    #define _CRT_STDIO_INLINE __inline
                              ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(1497): error: inline declaration of '_vswprintf' not allowed in block scope [clang-diagnostic-error]
    int, __RETURN_POLICY_SAME, _CRT_STDIO_INLINE, __CRTDECL, _swprintf, _swprintf_s, _vswprintf, vswprintf_s,
                               ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(21): message: expanded from macro '_CRT_STDIO_INLINE'
    #define _CRT_STDIO_INLINE __inline

Done Clang Tidy
```

Answer (score 2):

Defining this macro fixed the problem: `-D _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE`

Just add that to the arguments for clang